# Is Jprofiler version 12.0.4 compatible with macos 13.4.1?

Tags: jprofiler

I am installing Jprofiler 12.0.4 and my MacOS version is 13.4.1, After the installation when I start the JProfiler, it shows me all the menu items however I can't expand any of the menu items by clicking them.

I just want to know about the compatibility of this jprofiler version with various OS, JRE and it's versions

I tried intalling the latest jProfiler version 14.0.0 and it works but my license only works with 12.0.4 version and I need somehow 12.0.4 version running.

Comment: Unfortunately, the changes in macOS 13 prevent the JProfiler 12 UI from working correctly. You would have to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: i'm getting the same issue. I can't even open the newest dmg to install the new version. How do i run the dmg using the command line to see the error it's getting?